# Pop-up doesn't disappear by webscraping with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to parse a table from https://www.morningstar.de/de/screener/fund.aspx#?filtersSelectedValue=%7B%22sustainabilityRating%22:%7B%22id%22:%225%22%7D%7D&page=1&perPage=10&sortField=legalName&sortOrder=asc.

However, by opening the website with selenium I always get at first a pop-up, to close which I need to select type of user (`radiobutton`) and then click on "accept" button .

After I proceed these "clicks" with the help of python and selenium, the pop-up doesn't  disappear sbut I can see that clicks were proceeded. It doesn't show any error (all the needed fields are selected and python script also doesn't throw anything).

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url="https://www.morningstar.de/de/screener/fund.aspx#?filtersSelectedValue=%7B%22sustainabilityRating%22:%7B%22id%22:%225%22%7D%7D&page=1&perPage=10&sortField=legalName&sortOrder=asc"
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

try:
    radio_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/label/span/span[1]')[0]
    radio_button.click()
    time.sleep(3)

    accept_button=browser.find_element_by_id('_evidon-accept-button')
    accept_button.click()
    print("accepted")
except:
    print(" something went wrong")
```

I need to close this pop-up in order to get access to the table, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*Example for radio button `#finaprofessional > span:nth-child(1)` or `#finaprofessional > span:nth-child(2)`*

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


def example():
    firefox_browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    firefox_browser.get("https://www.morningstar.de/de/screener/fund.aspx#?filtersSelectedValue=%7B%22sustainabilityRating%22:%7B%22id%22:%225%22%7D%7D&page=1&perPage=10&sortField=legalName&sortOrder=asc")

    time.sleep(10)  # wait for page to load
    radio_button = firefox_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#finaprofessional > span:nth-child(1)")
    radio_button.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    accept_button = firefox_browser.find_element_by_id("_evidon-accept-button")
    accept_button.click()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    example()
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am afraid it doesn't help me: my problem was that after clicking on "accept" button the pop-up doesn't go away. I have tried your code and made css selector for accept_button as well but pop-up is still present,

Comment: @ulie change the time.sleep to 10 `time.sleep(10)` then run test again

Comment: thank you,  I did, but somehow pop-up doesn't go away (I get no error). I see that radiobutton and accept_button are clicked, but pop-up is still pinned, though when I check manually and proceed the same clicks, pop-up goes away.

Comment: @ulie it does work for me, I'm on python 3.8, what about you? browser?

Comment: I have python 3.8.2, firefox 75.0 . I have just tried the same with chrome(81.0.4044.92), still the same result

Comment: sorry couldn't help, hopefully someone will come around with different idea @ulie

Comment: there is something like a box "Best Ideas"  (right down) and the first row -"Nachhaltigkeits Research" should lead to this link